# How to monitor Kusto / Azure Data Explorer query result?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

The [Monitor section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-metrics) only talks about monitoring the ADX instance / server and performance and ingestion. Is there an Azure tool that monitors results of a Kusto query? Where can I find the documentation?

For example, receiving an alert when a Kusto query like `event | where isnotempty(error)` has result (number of rows > 0)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Azure logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/logicapps) or [Microsoft power automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/flow). It will allow you to create alerts over results from Kusto queries.